# Python - jinja2 template picks up only the first record from the data

Tags: python, pandas, jinja2, folium

I would like to make the on-click feature with a circle coming up when clicking on the marker.
So far I've developed the class which includes relevant elements as shown in the code below:

```
df = pd.read_csv("survey.csv")

class Circle(MacroElement):

def __init__(self):
    for i,row in df.iterrows():
        rad = int(df.at[i, 'radius'])

def __init__(self,
             popup=None
             ):
    super(Circle, self).__init__()
    self._name = 'Circle',
    self.radius = rad * 1560
    
    self._template = Template(u"""
        {% macro script(this, kwargs) %}
            var circle_job = L.circle();
            function newCircle(e){
                circle_job.setLatLng(e.latlng).addTo({{this._parent.get_name()}});
                circle_job.setRadius({{this.radius}});
                circle_job.setStyle({
                color: 'black',
                fillcolor: 'black'
                });
                };
            {{this._parent.get_name()}}.on('click', newCircle);      
        {% endmacro %}
        """)  # noqa
    



for i,row in df.iterrows():
lat =df.at[i, 'lat']
lng = df.at[i, 'lng']
sp = df.at[i, 'sp']
phone = df.at[i, 'phone']
role = df.at[i, 'role']
rad = int(df.at[i, 'radius'])


popup = '<b>Phone: </b>' + str(df.at[i,'phone'])
job_range = Circle()

if role == 'Contractor':
    fs.add_child(
        folium.Marker(location=[lat,lng],
                  tooltip=folium.map.Tooltip(
                      text='<strong>Contact surveyor</strong>',
                      style=("background-color: lightgreen;")),
                  popup=popup,
                  icon = folium.Icon(color='darkred', icon='glyphicon-user'
                                     )
                )
    )
    fs.add_child (
        folium.Marker(location=[lat,lng],
                  popup=popup,
                  icon = folium.DivIcon(html="<b>" + sp + "</b>",
                                        class_name="mapText_contractor",
                                        icon_anchor=(30,5))
                  #click_action = js_f
                )
    )
    fs.add_child(job_range)
```

which works but unfortunately takes into account only the very first record.

[image]

How could I make these pop-up circles adjusted to the radius of the given input (as presented in the CSV document?)?

Comment: If the end goal is to draw markers on the map and then draw circles on popup open or click event, I will suggest that you modify the `folium.Marker` template to include a javascript snippet on such a click event. The javascript code will then include a function to draw a circle when a popup is open.

Comment: I don't know how to do it. I tried with click_action attribute, but it didn't work at all.

Comment: See provided answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change the marker template to include a click function. The click function will open the popup and draw a circle. See example below.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import folium
from folium.map import Template, Marker

start_coords = (52.4972664,-2.0037126)
m = folium.Map(start_coords)


def generate_data(start_coords, n):
    roles = {0: 'Full', 1: 'Contractor'}
    df = pd.DataFrame()
    df['lat'] = [start_coords[0]+i for i in np.random.uniform(-1, 1, n)]
    df['lon'] = [start_coords[1]+i for i in np.random.uniform(-1, 1, n)]
    df['phone'] = [''.join(map(str, i)) for i in np.random.randint(1, 10, (n, 11))]
    df['radius'] = [10*i for i in np.random.randint(1, 9, n)]
    df['role'] = [roles[i] for i in np.random.randint(0, 2, n)]
    
    return df


# Modify Marker template to include the onClick event
click_template = """{% macro script(this, kwargs) %}
    var {{ this.get_name() }} = L.marker(
        {{ this.location|tojson }},
        {{ this.options|tojson }}
    ).addTo({{ this._parent.get_name() }}).on('click', addCircle).on('popupclose', removeCircle);
{% endmacro %}"""

# Change template to custom template
Marker._template = Template(click_template)

map_id = m.get_name()
#Add javascript snippet to draw cricles
click_js = f"""function removeCircle() {{
                 {map_id}.eachLayer(function(layer){{
                   if (layer instanceof L.Circle)
                      {{ {map_id}.removeLayer(layer) }}
                      }});
                }}


               function addCircle(e) {{                
                 coords = e.latlng                                 
                 var radius = e.target.options.radius * 1560; 
                 var color = e.target.options.circleColor;               
                 removeCircle() //remove existing circles                
                      
                 var circle = L.circle([coords.lat,coords.lng], {{radius: radius}}).addTo({map_id}) 
                 circle.setStyle({{
                    color: color,
                    fillcolor: color
                }});
                 }}"""
                 

e = folium.Element(click_js)
html = m.get_root()
html.script.add_child(e)

n = 10 # number of markers
df = generate_data(start_coords, n)

for i, row in df.iterrows():
    popup = f'<b>Phone: {row["phone"]}</b>' 
    icon_color = 'darkred' if row['role'] == 'Contractor' else 'black'
    folium.Marker([row['lat'], row['lon']],
                  popup=popup,
                  icon = folium.Icon(color=icon_color, icon='glyphicon-user'),
                  radius=row['radius'],
                  circleColor=icon_color
                 ).add_to(m)
    
m.fit_bounds(m.get_bounds())
m
```

Comment: I think we are close. I just got the Typeerror, that: Map object is not callable.

Comment: Do you know which line is giving you that TypeError?

Comment: Yes, it's exactly: df = generate_data(start_coords, n)

Comment: I don't see a variable called `Map` in that `generate_data` function unless you modified the example provided above.

Comment: I've just changed m to map as per my working file

Comment: Another line which refers to the same error is: df['phone'] = [''.join(map(str, i)) for i in np.random.randint(1, 10, (n, 11))]

Comment: That is why you have an error, because the `generate_data` function uses the `map`  function from the standard Python library. Change the folium map variable to another name except map, you can call it my_map or something

Comment: Ok I see it works in standalone version. However the color doesn't change. Is there a way to set the condition-based circle color changes?

Comment: I see, that this function applies to my all layers whereas I need them for one. I cannot run popup, as I have an error: Uncaught Error: Circle radius cannot be NaN
Do you now how assign this action just to one layer instead of eachLayer(function(layer)?